# can an order [as a document] state something?

Tags: phrase-requests

For example, a head of any department in a company gives instructions for personnel. These instructions are subject to formal procedures, i.e. documentation, approval, an internal newsletter. So these instructions are prepared in the form of an official document named the Order of the Head.

> Can you say that the order states that someone should do something, etc?

If no, maybe you can say that the order is dedicated to the fact that [...]? What do you write to specify the content of this document in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know precisely how formal this document is, but certainly a document can state other things beyond what it actually orders. So the Second Amendment to the US Constitution says that a well-regulated militia is necessary to the country, but *directs* that the right to bear arms shall not be infringed.

Comment: The distinction here is clear and useful.  The document *states* or *asserts* some of its content, *directs* or *requires* other parts.  Since the question refers to something that "the order is dedicated to", it's likely that "the order *requires* that someone do something" is the more appropriate option in this case.

Comment: Had it said "necessary to the country" I would argue it commands it, but with "for the security of a free state" it feels it merely says it as opposed to the _directs_ part; if mere things can be said in the context of such an instrument. But that's the thing here the _Head_ reference calls for such a top down/hierarchical lexicon. What if this _edict_ of the Head had contained a _service level agreement_ for instance. I wonder if it would then dictate, command, prescribe, direct... or settle, dispose(of), regulate, etc. Is is about the words or the rules proper? +1

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly...

You see inanimate objects "saying" things all the time:

The law says...

My lease says...

The Constitution says...

ad nauseam.

By today's usage. no one would be shocked if you said, "the Order of the Head says you must follow these steps: ..."

If anything, "The Order of the Head states..." is one step up in formality, and is most definitely appropriate. Many other verbs or introductory clauses can be used to convey the message with similar relaxed formality:

According to the Order of the Head, ...

In keeping with the Order of the Head, ...

As set out in the Order of the Head, ...

The Order of the Head specifies...

The Order of the Head defines...

The Order of the Head identifies...

The Order of the Head  sets out...

The Order of the Head spells out...

The Order of the Head describes...

ad nauseam again for the second time.

These may be more appropriate in a formal sense, but don't hesitate to send an informal email, text, whatever, to your audience and say, "Hey guys, don't forget the the Order of the Head says we must..."